# Cannot debug code with Azure ML workspace + VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to remotely debug Python code in an Azure ML workspace using VS Code 1.64.2. I have Azure ML extension installed in VS Code.

I can connect to Azure ML workspace and most of the features work ok. I'd like to start remote debugging following a tutorial on youtube. However I cannot do it because when I right-click a python file, there is no `Azure ML: Run as Experiment in Azure` menu which I can see in the video.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To attach VS Code to debugpy inside the container, open VS Code and use the F5 key or select Debug. When prompted, select the Azure Machine Learning Deployment: Docker Debug configuration.

You can also select the Run extension icon from the side bar, the Azure Machine Learning Deployment: Docker Debug entry from the Debug dropdown menu, and then use the green arrow to attach the debugger.

[image]

---

@Alexey, You can go through this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-debug-visual-studio-code#:%7E:text=To%20attach%20VS%20Code%20to,Learning%20Deployment%3A%20Docker%20Debug%20configuration.) for detailed steps for Interactive debugging with VS code

Comment: AbhishekKhandave-MT, thank you, but I do not have `Azure Machine Learning Deployment: Docker Debug` option either.